# Alternatives to Export to write long list as a table on a file

Tags: export, memory

I have a large list (approx 50 millions elements).

I could `Export` it as a table like this:

```
Export["path/to/file.dat",list,"Table"]
```

but this takes a large amount of memory. Are there any alternatives for writing my list on a file as a table, which use less RAM?

Comment: Would other target formats also take up as much memory? Eg HDF5, NASACDF, ...

Answer (score 3):

You can do a batched export using an output stream. For example:

```
batchedExport[file_, data_List, format_, n_Integer] := Module[{
   stream = OpenAppend[file]
   },
  WithCleanup[
   Scan[
    Function[
     WriteString[
      stream,
      ExportString[#, format] <> "\n"
      ]
     ],
    Partition[data, UpTo[n]]
    ];
   file
   ,
   Close[stream]
   ]
 ];

data = RandomChoice[{1, 2., "a"}, {100000, 4}];
batchedExport["test.dat", data, "Table", 100]
```

You can use `n` to change the amount of data that gets processed each step.